# Is it possible to split a function into multiple function and still have the continuity/original result

Tags: python, pandas

Have the below code

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=None)
def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    global df
for sc in ticks:
    token=sc['instrument_token']
    name=trd_portfolio[token]['name']
    ltp=sc['last_price']
    df1=pd.DataFrame([name,ltp]).T
    df1.columns=['name','ltp']
    df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)

    df['change']=df.groupby('name')['ltp'].pct_change()
    g = df.groupby('name')['change']
    g = g.agg(
    pos_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum(),
    neg_count=lambda s: s.lt(0).sum(),
    net_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum()- s.lt(0).sum()).astype(int)
    g=g.sort_values(by=['net_count'])

    print(g)
```

would want to split the function after appending to the data frame,ie. after '''df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)'''

so that the calculation from the data capture can be processed more efficiently.

I tried splitting and using async function but could not get the print output.

Comment: Can you explain `would want to split the function after appending to the data frame,ie. after`?, it seems unclear, also make sure to include the sample of dataframes.

Comment: I meant that i wanted to split the function after like 10 where the code is  df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True), the final output is           pos_count  neg_count  net_count
name                                     
63MOONS           0          0          0
NIACL             0          0          0
NIITTECH          0          0          0

            ...        ...        ...


HSIL              0          0          0
ICICIGI           0          0          0
ZEEL              0          0          0

[247 rows x 3 columns]

Comment: Each function should do one thing and then tie all the functions together in a `main` function. [Real Python: Defining Main Functions in Python](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/)